# Concatenate n-values of dictionary to create a new value for a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, concatenation

I want to create a new value for a new list from n-concatenated values of a dictionary, as strange as it sounds I want something as described below.

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'A': 9, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 7, 'E': 6, 'F': 8, 'G': 5, 'H': 3, 'I': 4}
{'A': 9, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 5, 'E': 3, 'F': 4, 'G': 7, 'H': 6, 'I': 8}
{'A': 7, 'B': 6, 'C': 8, 'D': 9, 'E': 1, 'F': 2, 'G': 5, 'H': 3, 'I': 4}
{'A': 7, 'B': 6, 'C': 8, 'D': 5, 'E': 3, 'F': 4, 'G': 9, 'H': 1, 'I': 2}
{'A': 5, 'B': 3, 'C': 4, 'D': 7, 'E': 6, 'F': 8, 'G': 9, 'H': 1, 'I': 2}
{'A': 5, 'B': 3, 'C': 4, 'D': 9, 'E': 1, 'F': 2, 'G': 7, 'H': 6, 'I': 8}
```

and I want the result as a new list, for example my_list[0] = ABC values , my_list[1] = DEF values and so on which will be displayed as 912, 768, 534 for the first row of my dictionary. The sorting does matter, it must remain as it is.

I am new to Python 3.x and I cannot find something similar to this problem. All I have achieved is to print the values only, one after another with the below script:

```
res_list = {frozenset(item.items()) : item for item in my_dictionary}.values() 
for x in solutions:
  for elem in x.keys():
      print(x[elem])
```

Can I iterate the values and concat them per 3 steps? My goal here is to create a list of 3 digit numbers and compare these values for duplicates so that the result will be in my case just 3 distinct numbers that the sorting here does not matter.

```
912, 768, 345
```

Comment: "Is there any way" is a non-issue for Stack Overflow. Since you're on a general-purpose computer that is barely short of a Turing machine, the answer is almost always "yes". The follow-up question, "How do I do it?", is too broad for Stack Overflow.  You need to iterate in groups / steps of 3; work on that.

Comment: Prune there are so many questions here with the general question if this or that is possible, "Is there any way" was never written here. I am no expert and I am trying to learn, if you don't know the answer the only thing you offered here as a member is just bitterness that I think it's too unnecessary for Stack Overflow.

Comment: No, this is a short attempt to get to to mold your question into something suitable for Stack Overflow.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  As you say, there are many questions here -- which makes the post unsuitable for this site.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your question may be schematic and so your dictionary keys may not actually be `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'` etc.

But given that proviso, does this help?

```
>>> mydict = {'A': 9, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 7, 'E': 6, 'F': 8, 'G': 5, 'H': 3, 'I': 4}
>>> mylist = [int(''.join(str(mydict[k]) for k in group)) for group in ('ABC','DEF','GHI')]
>>> mylist
[912, 768, 534]
```

Comment: Thank you @BoarGules for your help, this does not work as it gives me an error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: I pasted that from IDLE. It is correct as it stands. I would check your definition of `mydict` since the error message suggests you have defined it as a list and in the example it is defined as a dict.